# Bind to dynamically added settings?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

this is my first post here. Though this website has provided answers for most of my problems I couldn't find anything to help me with this situation.

I am working on an dashboard like application that displays results of a variety of sql queries. The available queries are read dynamically from XML.

The user can select which results to show and save the selection.

Rather than maintaining the queries and the corresponding Properties.Settings separately I am trying to add the settings dynamically.

```
SettingsProperty property = new SettingsProperty(Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["defaultSetting"]);
property.Name = "newSettingFromQueryName";
Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Add(property);
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
```

The above works perfectly for creating the setting, however my binding between the checked state of my checkboxes and the corresponding setting is broken.
This doesn't seem to work with dynamically added settings:

```
CheckBox infoCardSelectionCheckBox = new CheckBox();
Binding checkBoxBinding = new Binding();
checkBoxBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
checkBoxBinding.Source = Properties.Settings.Default;
checkBoxBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("newSettingFromQueryName");
infoCardSelectionCheckBox.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, checkBoxBinding);
infoCardSelectionGrid.Children.Add(infoCardSelectionCheckBox);
```

I noticed that while the new setting is accessible via `Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["newSettingFromQueryName"]` it isn't via `Properties.Settings.Default.newSettingFromQueryName`.

I suspect that's where my problem is and why the binding fails.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance
Manuel